# Setting foreign key relationships in a table with composite PK

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the below tables in my database:

```
Public class Student
{
  [Key]
  string Id {get; set;}
  string Department {get; set;}

  #region Navigation properties 
  public virtual ICollection<Courses> Courses{get; set;} ----> Parent to child
  #endregion
}

Public class Courses
{
  [Key]
  [Column(Order = 1)]
  string Name{get; set;}
  [Key]
  [Column(Order = 2)]
  string StudentId {get; set;}
  string MaxCredits

  #region Navigation Properties
  [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
  public virtual Student Student {get; set;}  ----> Child to parent 
 }
```

In the Courses table, the course name is not unique hence the need for a Composite Primary Key. Therefore, as per the above definition, I have a foreign key in my child table that is part of the composite primary key in the same table. Is this relationship valid?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Also, maybe adding a `CourseId` field and defining *that* as the primary key would not be a bad idea.

Comment: @sstan: I did consider adding a new column and defining that as the primary key, but business requirements don't permit me to do so. I did try out the relationship and I did not get any errors.